# Computing integral over unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, power-series, laurent-series

> Compute \begin{equation}I=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C(0,1)}z^n\exp\left(\frac{2}{z}\right)\textrm{d}z\end{equation} where $C(0,1)$ is the unit circle centred at $0$ oriented anticlockwise, for integer values $n$.

My solution: Note the Laurent expansion of $\exp(z)=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots$, hence $\exp\left(\frac{2}{z}\right)=1+\frac{2}{z}+\cdots +\frac{z^k}{k!2^k}+\cdots $. Hence we have that $z^n\exp\left(\frac{2}{z}\right)=z^n+2z^{n-1}+\cdots +\frac{z^{k+n}}{k!2^k}$. Then to determine the residue we need only look at the coefficient of $1/z$, for a particular $n$. Is this correct?

Comment: wait isnt your function exp(2/z^2), not exp(2/z)? is this a typo

Comment: @CaptainChicky indeed it is $2/z$ - thanks for pointing this out! Ill edit this now. In this case is my solution right?

Comment: Put $k=-n$ and then see the coefficient of $z^{-1}$. That will be the answer.

Comment: @alidixon222 yep you are right! The answer below gives the definite value for any $n$ :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(z)=z^ne^{\frac {2}{z}}$$

$$z^ne^{\frac {2}{z}}= \sum_{m=0}^\infty 2^m\frac{z^{(-m+n)}}{m!}(*)$$

By definition $Res(f,0)=a_{-1}$ of the Laurent series $(*)$. So we want $-m+n=-1\implies m=n+1\implies \operatorname{Res}(f,0)=a_{-1}=\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$